# Traffic light program using while loop in python

Tags: traffic, light

I am trying to run this code in python and I want the code to stop looping when the user enters 30, here I have used break to stop the loop, is there any other way? Any suggestion would be helpful.

```
`x = input("Enter value: ")
stop_light = int(x)
while True:
    if stop_light >= 1 and stop_light < 10:
        print('Green light')
        stop_light += 1
    elif stop_light < 20:
        print('Yellow light')
        stop_light += 1
    elif stop_light < 30:
        print("Red light")
        stop_light += 1
    else:
        stop_light = 0
    break`
```

Comment: Your code does not loop.  If the user inputs a number, the code finds the appropriate condition, prints, breaks, and ends.  If I input `28`, I get a print output of `Red light` and that's it.  Are you getting the result that you want?

Comment: If  you want to iterate from an input number till 30 then remove break statement and replace last statement "stop_light = 0" to "break"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm I'm not quite sure what you actually want to achieve. Your version does not loop since the break statement will always be met after the first iteration.
Additionally, you only ask for user input once before the loop actually starts.

Here is what I suppose you want to do, so I moved the user input part inside the loop and added the break condition to the pythonic "switch" statement. This will just ask the user for input for as long as he doesn't enter 30.

```
while True:
    x = input("Enter value: ")
    stop_light = int(x)
    if stop_light == 30:
        break
    elif stop_light >= 1 and stop_light < 10:
        print('Green light')
        stop_light += 1
    elif stop_light < 20:
        print('Yellow light')
        stop_light += 1
    elif stop_light < 30:
        print("Red light")
        stop_light += 1
    else:
        stop_light = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have already mentioned, your code does not loop.  However, this code does:

```
while True:
    try:
        x = input("Enter value: ")
        stop_light = int(x)
    except ValueError:
        print("Try Again")
    else:
        break

while stop_light <= 30:
    if stop_light >= 1 and stop_light < 10:
        print('Green light')
    elif stop_light < 20:
        print('Yellow light')
    elif stop_light < 30:
        print("Red light")
    stop_light += 1
```

In this, I am utilizing a condition in the while loop.  The condition is for the loop to iterate the user value until it becomes `30`.  The reason for this is because of your condition in the `Red light` line.  I explained this further in the **Problem #2** below.

Take notice that I am catching `ValueError` before proceeding.

Also there is only one of `stop_light += 1`.

Here are some sample outputs:

```
Enter value: asdf
Try Again
Enter value: 27
Red light
Red light
Red light
# Breaks and closes the code.

Enter value: 5
Green light
Green light
Green light
Green light
Green light
Yellow light
Yellow light
Yellow light
Yellow light
Yellow light
Yellow light
Yellow light
Yellow light
Yellow light
Yellow light
Red light
Red light
Red light
Red light
Red light
Red light
Red light
Red light
Red light
Red light
# Breaks and closes the code.
```

Now, these are the problems with your code:

**Problem #1**

```
else:
    stop_light = 0
```

This portion doesn't properly handle negative numbers and numbers greater than `30`.  I don't think you wanted to iterate 30 times for the values that fall into that condition since you didn't apply `stop_light += 1` in your code.  So, you definitely have to think about what the purpose of this is.

Check out the following code that constantly loops until the value is greater than `30`:

```
while True:
    try:
        x = input("Enter value: ")
        stop_light = int(x)
    except ValueError:
        print("Try Again")
    else:
        while stop_light < 30:
            if stop_light >= 1 and stop_light < 10:
                print('Green light')
            elif stop_light < 20:
                print('Yellow light')
            elif stop_light < 30:
                print("Red light")
            stop_light += 1
        if stop_light > 30:
            break

Output:

Enter value: asdf
Try Again
Enter value: 27
Red light
Red light
Red light
Enter value: 31
# Breaks and closes the code.
```

**Problem #2**

The reason why I scripted to loop until the value is greater than 30 is because of the following lines in your code:

```
elif stop_light < 30:
    print("Red light")
    stop_light += 1
```

If you wanted the loop to break only when the user inputs `30`, then those lines of code above works against that theory.  Your loop will break even when `stop_light` is `29` due to the incrementation of `stop_light`.  You should also look into this flaw of your logic.

Comment: Thanks and that break was not indented properly here, I used it inside the else.

Answer (score 0):

while True:
x = input("Enter value (q to quit): ")
if x == 'q':
break
stop_light = int(x)

```
while True:
    if stop_light >= 1 and stop_light < 10:
        print('Green light')
        stop_light += 1
    elif stop_light < 20:
        print('Yellow light')
        stop_light += 1
    elif stop_light < 30:
        print("Red light")
        stop_light += 1
    else:
        stop_light = 0
    if stop_light == 0:
        break
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).